# Localize iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, internationalization, nslocalizedstring

I have a basic iPhone/iPad app which has a ;
a. List view & 
b. Detail view

The list view displays a set of list (Link 1, Link 2, Link 3, etc) in a table view

On click of any of the links, the corresponding detail view is shown (Detail view 1, Detail view 2, Detail view 3, etc)
The detail view is actually shown within a web view (so actually a page of http://mySite.com/Detail1.html, http://mySite.com/Detail2.html, etc are displayed)

Nopw my question is my detail view is currently shown in English language only. So is there some way by which I can show the content in different languages (not sure if we would have control over the external web view displayed content). Converting the list view to different languages would also be good, but my main thing is within the "detail" web view. It is actually lots of text content/data.

Please help me and suggest how do I convert them to display different languages dynamically.
Also any statistics to display if converting to local languages help improve sales would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at NSLocalizedString(NSString, NSString). It allows you do localize strings in your ObjC part of your application. This will allow you to translate your list view.

To localize the details page you will have to create a new detail page for every language and then use NSLocalizedString to localize the links the to the detail pages.

Hope I could point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Hello World", @"hello message")
```